# Magento 2 : setup:upgrade throwing error. After Magento 2.1 to 2.3 update

Tags: magento2, version, setup-upgrade

I recently updated my Magento version form 2.1 to 2.3.0.

Update was successful in my local system.

Now its throwing error while running setup:upgrade like this.

```
Schema creation/updates:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Declaration\SchemaBuilder::processTable() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\Table, boolean returned in /var/www/html/store/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php:251
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/store/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php(148): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Declaration\SchemaBuilder->processTable(Object(Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\Schema), Array)
#1 /var/www/html/store/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/SchemaConfig.php(78): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Declaration\SchemaBuilder->build(Object(Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\Schema))
#2 /var/www/html/store/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/DeclarationInstaller.php(57): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\SchemaConfig->getDeclarationConfig()
#3 /var/www/html/store/setup/s in /var/www/html/store/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php on line 251
```

Checked on log files. There is no error except.

debug.log

> main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: 
>   {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}}
>   []

Comment: issue must be because of your any third party module's setup schema, so please try upgrade with disable your third party extensions.